# Angular nvd3 Stack Area Chart- Expand Option - 0% to 100% range

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, nvd3.js

I am having a little trouble with the stacked area chart. The issue when I click the "expand" option. the expand option has a y-axis range of 0% to 100%, yet the values are y * 100%.

For example, take this data set...

```
x [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

y [0, 140, 451, 867, 903, 960, 1000]

140 + 451 + 867 + 903 + 960 + 1000 = 4321

960 / 4321 * 100% = 22.21%
```

With the expand option therefore the value 960 is 960% when I want it to equal a the actual percentage of 22.21%.

1. Is there a means in which to format the data such that y value will adjust to a 0%-100% range in the "expand" style?
2. Or, is there a way to listen for when user clicks the "expand" option?

Answer (score 0):

If your area graph is working correctly as a stream or stacked graph it should automatically work expanded. One possible issue - if you set a yDomain or forceY attribute then your expanded view will not work.

Comment: Expanding the graph is not the issue.  The issue is the tooltip is showing the wrong percentage value when it is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 12863 in nv.d3 and edit the code to this...

```
    stacked.dispatch.on('elementMouseover.tooltip', function(evt) {

    evt.point['x'] = stacked.x()(evt.point);
    if(stacked.style() == 'expand'){
            evt.point['y'] = evt.point.display.y;
    }else{  evt.point['y'] = stacked.y()(evt.point);}

    tooltip.data(evt).position(evt.pos).hidden(false);
});
```